# Add labels as threads in a QtWindow

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, label

i've been trying to create a program in Python that randomly creates dinamic labels on a window, using threads. But something is wrong, couls someone help me please?

I've tried using a thread to call the "animation" function, but it just don't works.

CODE:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'bt.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
import threading
import time

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(473, 700)
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(473, 700))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(473, 700))
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 473, 700))
        self.label.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("images/bg.png")))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 610, 273, 28))
        self.label_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.label_2.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.label_2.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("images/click.png")))
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
        self.label_2.mousePressEvent = self.openGame
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Breaking Thread", None))

    def openGame(self, event):
        GameWindow.show()
        MainWindow.close()
        t1.start()
        t1.join()

class Ui_GameWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, GameWindow):
        GameWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("GameWindow"))
        GameWindow.resize(473, 700)
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(GameWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        GameWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        GameWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(473, 700))
        GameWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(473, 700))
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(GameWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 473, 700))
        self.label.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("images/bg2.png")))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        GameWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(GameWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(GameWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, GameWindow):
        GameWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("GameWindow", "Breaking Thread", None))

    def animation(self):
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(GameWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.label_3 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 60, 30, 30))
        self.label_3.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.label_3.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("images/bg.png")))
        self.label_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_3"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)

    GameWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    gi = Ui_GameWindow()
    gi.setupUi(GameWindow)

    t1 = threading.Thread(target=gi.animation())

    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this - GUI operations *must* [happen in the main thread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html#gui-thread-and-worker-thread).

If you want to do something in a secondary thread, use signals and slots to communicate with the main thread and do the GUI updates there.

Comment: Thank you very much! I found a really good article explaining how to do that here: https://joplaete.wordpress.com/2010/07/21/threading-with-pyqt4/